# Asp.net calling C# layer calling Managed C++ calling Native C++

Tags: c#, asp.net, c++, unmanaged, managed-c++

My project structure is as follow:

**ASP.NET** calling **C#** layer calling **Managed** C++ calling **Native** C++
*(i'm trying to avoid using interop so this is why the managed c++ layer)*
I wrote  unit test that test the C# layer and it works fine.
When I try to run the asp.net page i'm getting: `"Could not load file or assembly..."` error.
I figured out that when i copy paste the **Native C++** dll to "Temporary ASP.NET Files" (to the corresponding folder) the site works.

It seems that the **Managed C++** code can find the **Native C++** code only if it resides in the same folder - obviously I can't have my Native dll in the temp files.

Is there a way to set the Native in a global place(doesn't work with System32)?

Thanks for you comments.

### It boils down to one option:

1. It is security issue

i set up the server it self with the code and it runs under the cassini, but when i publish it(to run under iis7) i'm getting "Could not load file or assembly ...."
i'm running IIS7 with ApplicationPoolIdentity , .net 4 Integrated 
Thanks a lot,
Pini.

Comment: Are you sure that copying the native dll to System32 didn't work?  As long as that folder is in your path it should load successfully.

Comment: You may have a 64bits/32bits compatibility problem. If your server is 64 bits and your native dll is 32 bits you should try building your managed code as X86 and copying your native dll(s) to Syswow64 instead of System32

Comment: Interesting point!! My server is 64bits. I don't think this is the issue because I'm able to build and run the code (all layers) on the server(I've vs2010 there) but under the Cassini. The problem is when I publish the code from the server locally then I'm getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to flip a bool in the ApplicationPoolIdentity. One of the filed in the properties says "enable 32bit" and that did the trick :) the default is False
My server is 64bit and i build my native with 32bit.

Answer (score 5):

Well technically using Managed C++ in this way is a form of Interop between native / managed code, the commonly used alternatives being COM and P/Invoke. This is purely a terminology thing however, you would get the same issue using P/Invoke.

This blog article [Loading C++ Assemblies in ASP.Net](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jorman/archive/2007/08/31/loading-c-assemblies-in-asp-net.aspx) might help you out - In short you need to either:

- Set the `%PATH%` environment variable before the Managed C++ assembly attempts to load your native C++ dll.
- Use the `DllImport` attribute to set the dll path (not applicable in your case as you aren't using P/Invoke)
- Manually load the C++ dll yourself (e.g. with `LoadLibrary`) before the Managed C++ assembly attempts to load your native C++ dll.

I suspect that installing your dll to Win SxS would also work, but I don't know enough about how this works to be sure.

Comment: Thanks Kragen, I've added the Native dll directory to the System Variables Path, restarted my computer and still getting the same error. Any idea? Maybe it is because of the way I reference the Native?

Comment: Ohhh... i do not know if it is important but i use WebDev.WebServer40.exe to run my asp.net page - aka casini. i haven't tried it yet on iis server.

Comment: @UshaP Oh, just remembered.  By default ASP.Net runs under a restricted user account that almost certainly won't have access to the System32 directory or other paths on the system (but will have access to the Temporary ASP.Net folder).  You should also make sure that whatever account ASP.Net is using has the required NTFS permissions to read the native dll.  As far as I am aware IIS vs Casini shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: I also suspect it is permission issue. I'm not sure how to set up the ASP.Net user. I think that cassini runs under my user name and i'm administrator on the box. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can set your path variable?

You set it by going to the Properties of "My computer"/"Computer (Windows-PauseBreak) and then clicking advanced settings. Click advanced. Environment variables. Modify "Path" under system variables as needed.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help see my comment to Kragen.

Comment: Have you checked your project dependencies?

Comment: it does work when i run my unit test and if i copy the native c++ to the asp.net temporary folder

Comment: Are the three projects in the same solution? Right click, and choose set project dependencies. The native dll should now properly be in the bin catalog with the managed dll.

Comment: Yes they are all in the same solution.In the managed project -> VC++ directories i set the include directories to to the Native path(hard code).